# I'm trying to find some duplicate values, but I think its counting wrong. Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using a few simply queries, but it's not gathering the data I want.
My first query is to try and find duplicate values.

```
SELECT MY_NUM,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY MY_NUM
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Which returns

| MY_NUM | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
|  | 6219 |

Which I thought means there are 6219 null values for MY_NUM but then I use this query.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1
 WHERE MY_NUM IS NULL;
```

Which returns

| MY_NUM | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 | COLUMN... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I thought these would be simple queries. My goal is to find duplicates and null values for MY_NUM.

Comment: I suspect that the issue with the second query is the tool you are using to look at the results.  Or that `MY_NUM` could be a string consisting of spaces or invisible characters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you know how I would check for that? MY_NUM is a string because it includes letters, but there should not be spaces or invisible characters.

Comment: just write query with MY_NUM IS NOT NULL and see if you see the blank spaces.

Comment: @TedoG. When I do that I can see where MY_NUM has blanks. Is there a way I can see only the data where MY_NUM is blank? I've tried MY_NUM = ''  and MY_NUM IS NULL for my WHERE clause, but they both result in a blank table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have null values but spaces. Could you please check?

```
with table1 (id, my_num) as(
    select 1, ' ' from dual)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    regexp_replace(my_num, '[[:space:]]+', NULL) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most common case Empty if not Null

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1
 WHERE MY_NUM = '';
```

MY_NUM contains empty value that is Not Null

To check other blanck string you can do :

```
SELECT '#'||MY_NUM||'#',count(*)
  FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY MY_NUM
 HAVING count(*)>1;
```

doing this you'll see how many blanck cahracter you have.

Comment: I just tried this. I got the same result. (a blank table)

Comment: Ok, I updated with my answer with a second check to do.

Comment: This query results in the same number I get from my first query. So I suppose it confirms the blanks are being counted correctly, but I still can't query all the data where MY_NUM is blank.

Comment: same number is normal, it's the same query, but what did you see? how many blanck(s) between # # ?

Comment: was this query supposed to show me the number of blank spaces between # #? If it was I didn't see anything like that, it just duplicated my first table.

Comment: If the first query duplicate your table, that's what you are looking for ... MY_NUM='' (Empy value and Empty Value is diffrent from Null)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Use your current query as a *subquery* and return rows from `table1` whose `my_num` has duplicate values.

```
select * 
from table1
where my_num in (select my_num
                 from table1
                 group by my_num
                 having count(*) > 1
                );
```

Also, if you don't know what `my_num` really is, `dump` it. For example:

```
SQL> select dump(' ') space_character,
  2         dump('A') letter_a,
  3         dump('')  empty_string
  4  from dual;

SPACE_CHARACTER  LETTER_A         EMPT
---------------- ---------------- ----
Typ=96 Len=1: 32 Typ=96 Len=1: 65 NULL

SQL>
```

Comment: Ah, this answers what I need to do next. Thank you. =)